# Turn 2-D list into 1-D with an index from the 2nd dimension

Tags: python, arrays, list

Let's say I have a list:

> > l = [ [1,2,3],[4,5,6] ]

Is there any Pythonic way to get a list of every second element of all inner lists without iterating and creating a new list?

The expected output would be:

> > l
> >     [2,5]

I appreciate any help! I have been searching around for a possible solution and have been unable to come across one.

Comment: Where are the numbers 2 and 5 coming from? How are the contents of the new list determined?

Comment: as jonrsharpe suggested, you'd better not name your list like a built-in function.

Comment: Gotcha in regards to the naming convention. The 2 and 5 come from index 1 of in the inner lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that is not bad:

```
>>> list = [ [1,2,3],[4,5,6] ]
>>> map(lambda el: el[1], list)
[2, 5]
```

Answer (score 2):

This is trivial in `numpy`, where the slice syntax is extended to multiple dimensions:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.arange(1, 7).reshape(2, 3)
>>> a
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
>>> a[:,1]
array([2, 5])
```

In vanilla lists, you'd have to iterate and create the list, e.g. using a list comprehension:

```
>>> lst = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> [l[1] for l in lst]
[2, 5]
```

or using [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) with [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> map(itemgetter(1), lst)
[2, 5]
```

*(Note that you shouldn't call your own variable `list`, as it shadows the built-in.)*

Answer (score 1):

`zip()` in conjunction with the * operator can be used to unzip a list:

```
>>> zip(*l)
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
>>> zip(*l)[1]
(2, 5)
```

With Python 3.x:

```
list(zip(*l))[1] #zip gives an iterator
```

Comment: Note that this will create a new list of the zipped tuples in 2.x, and will fail in 3.x

Comment: you're right, at least I've met the 'without iterating' criterion. Don't know if you could do both.

Comment: why would it fail with 3.x BTW? I guess it wouldn't.

Comment: `zip` creates an iterator, not a list, in 3.x (see https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#views-and-iterators-instead-of-lists) - indexing it gives `TypeError: 'zip' object is not subscriptable`.

Answer (score 0):

```
list = [ [1,2,3],[4,5,6] ]

#This will do it, but requires iteration
list = [subList[1] for subList in list]

#This does it *without* iteration, but really 
#it's just the unwinding of a very small loop,
#which is jsut a way of cheating around that
#stipulation, and it's not pythonic...
list = [list[0][1], list[1][1]]
```